# Object Passed by Reference Not Working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

New to iOS development. So I passed a method with an object address, thinking that I would be altering the same object by doing so:

```
_posts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

FetchPosts *dataControl = [[FetchPosts alloc]init];
[dataControl accessPosts: _posts];
```

And the below code receives the passed in object.

```
-(void)accessPosts: (NSMutableArray *)transition {
    //access the posts here.

    _readablePosts = transition;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"private"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    _jsonPosts = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [_jsonPosts appendData: data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_jsonPosts options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.count; i++) {

        NSDictionary *element = jsonArray[i];

        Posts *newPost = [[Posts alloc]init];

        newPost.title = element[@"Title"];
        newPost.discovery = element[@"Discovery"];
        newPost.summary = element[@"Description"];
        newPost.contact = element[@"Contact"];

        [_readablePosts addObject:newPost];

    }
}
```

From my perspective, everything seems to be in place properly. However, when I return to my original method, the _posts does not hold the correct object as it should. Am I doing something wrong with my pointers here?

Comment: Please add code, about the part where you actually mutate `_posts`.

Comment: what happens with `_readablePosts`? nothing acts on it in `accessPosts:` so why would it change at all?

Comment: Define "not the correct object as it should"

Comment: @Fonix I've added the methods that alter _readablePosts

Comment: You are using `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods. Did you set your class as the connection's delegate? Are these methods called?

Comment: Are you sure that the Json contain something?

Comment: @JózsefVesza Yes I did and they're called! Right after the for loop, I NSLogged this: _readablePosts.count and it worked.

Comment: So _readablePosts holds everything correctly as it should by the end of the function. However when I return back, _posts does not

Comment: Could it have something to do with Strong or weak?

Comment: Not really. An `NSMutableArray` property should be strong.

Comment: @JózsefVesza For some reason, _posts doesn't hold the correct object's reference. That's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call this method -

```
[dataControl accessPosts: _posts];
```

Which invokes

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

This is a non-blocking method, so it returns immediately and calls the delegate methods once it has retrieved data to be processed.

If you access `_posts` as soon `accessPosts` returns you will be doing so before the data has been retrieved from the network.

Only after `connectionDidFinishLoading:` has been called can you access the data in `_posts`

One solution is to use a delegation pattern.  Your outer code would set itself as a delegate to the `FetchPosts` object, with the delegate method being called from `connectionDidFinishLoading`.  Not only will this address your asynchronous issue it avoid potentially unsafe updating of the `NSMutableArray` and avoids the use of side-effects.

You will need to create an appropriate protocol in `FetchPosts.h` but then you can use something like -

```
-(void) requestPosts {
    FetchPosts *dataControl = [[FetchPosts alloc]init];
    dataControl.delegate=self;
    [dataControl accessPosts];
}

-(void) didReceiveNewPosts:(NSArray *)posts {
   // Do something with posts
}
```

**FetchPosts.m**

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_jsonPosts options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.count; i++) {

        NSDictionary *element = jsonArray[i];

        Posts *newPost = [[Posts alloc]init];

        newPost.title = element[@"Title"];
        newPost.discovery = element[@"Discovery"];
        newPost.summary = element[@"Description"];
        newPost.contact = element[@"Contact"];

        [_readablePosts addObject:newPost];

    }

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didReceiveNewPosts:)]) {
        [self.delegate didReceiveNewPosts:_readablePosts];
    }
}
```

Comment: A little confused. When we implement a protocol with did ReceiveNewPosts, does the original program wait until the protocol is triggered? How can we be sure by this that _posts will have the correct object when I use it? Is it because the protocol ensures that method must be evoked before returning to the original caller?

Comment: The original object doesn't 'wait' as such, but yes, the delegate method is invoked later when the network operation is completed.  Much of what you will do in iOS apps is event driven - you are responding to an event such as a tap on a UI item or the delivery of data from the network.  The runloop takes care of the waiting & scheduling

Comment: To try and clarify I have wrapped a method around your original fetch code - See how that method just exits once it has initiated the request.  The delegate method will be called at some later time to actually process the data.  Also be aware that the delegate method may be invoked on a background queue and any UI updates must be dispatched onto the main queue

Comment: Is there anyway to only use some methods in the original class after the protocol is triggered? Because otherwise my code still doesn't work properly. One of my table methods needs _posts.count but it should only do that if the protocol has been triggered. Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it with this puppy:     [self.tableView reloadData]; This will reload the data once the protocol method has been triggered. Done deal :)

Comment: Yes, you can also call any method you like from the delegate method - so you can call any original code you had

Answer (score 0):

I think that the json is empty, the method didReceiveData is called each time that the device obtain a chunk of data, this method can be called more times during a downloading. If you create a new mutable data and append data is like you are resetting the NSDAta object.
 
You should create the Json post object in didReceiveresponse.

Comment: Nope, that can't be it.  Right after the for loop, I NSLogged this: _readablePosts.count and it worked correctly as it should. The only issue is that _posts doesn't seem to hold the reference to the correct object once it is all done.

Comment: Even if is not the reason,because it downloads in just one round, you are implementing th delegate methods in not proper way.